# Java LibGDX Texture gives null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, libgdx, textures

I've been using LibGDX for a project and whenever i declare a Texture it gives :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.fistbump.patman.test.main(test.java:18)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140
```

The code is :

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;



public class test  {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Texture text = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Path.png"));
    OR
    Texture text = new Texture("Path.png");
}
```

}

I am really stuck here . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You cant use (the majority of) libGDX before it is initialized. This is in or after the `create` method of your `ApplicationListener` (or `ApplicationAdapter` or `Game` if your prefer).

See also: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/The-life-cycle

Comment: But i am making a class which has it's texture within . how can i do that inside the class

Comment: I'm not sure which class you're talking about, but your code clearly shows that you never initialized libGDX. Use the setup utility to create your project and only modify the core project. Don't modify the desktop project. Start here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle

Comment: very useful answer, i was scratching my head for this bug.